# What happens to zombied chat rooms?

Tags: discussion

There are several essentially dead *Mathematica* chat rooms that are the lingering remains of discussions between two people, where one one person left the room at the end of the discussion but the other didn't. I don't see this as a big problem, but I am curious as to what happens to such rooms in the long term. Is there some StackExchange script that eventually cleans them out, or do they just linger indefinitely?

Comment: Most of the time, after 14 days of no activity, they get deleted. The discussion ones just get frozen without being deleted, presumably because they are considered to be an extension of the discussion in comments that gave rise to them.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention